# TINYTEXT Calculation in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

MYSQL Database:

I have a field in a Table Column1 contain the Price value, but declared as TINYTEXT.

I need to multiply the price by 100,  but i i cast that value, no value is coming.

I tried both the below option.

```
  SELECT CAST(Column1 as UNSIGNED) * 100  

   SELECT CAST(Column1 as SIGNED) * 100
```

TINYTEXT Sample Data

```
$19.99      
$11.99
```

its a Dolloar Sign  ($19.99  and sometimes value is not present in that column.
Regards
Vikram.

Comment: Show us all variations of the text you can find in there. Do they have a dollar sign, commas, periods, etc?

Comment: I think `signed` is only a modifier for a MySQL data type, not a data type itself.  Try `cast(col1 as dec(10,2))` for a decimal with 10 digits of which two are behind the comma.

Comment: Yes its a Dolloar Sign  ($19.99  and sometimes value is not present in that column.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you will have to process the string in there to sanitize the data. Based on the fact that `$19.99` is the only variation then it seems safe just to replace the dollar sign:

```
SELECT REPLACE(price, '$', '') * 100 FROM t
```

However, you should seriously consider turning that column into `DECIMAL`. That way you won't face a bug when someone adds an euro or pound sign.